# Tomcat 8 high cpu usage thread

Tags: tomcat

I have application running on tomcat 8. Noticed my server cpu usage is high during that time my thread dump shows below stack trace. Theses classes is belongs to tomcat web server.

I like to understand why these thread shows up in the high cpu usage. Any tips will be helpful to track down this issue.

```
Thread "ajp-nio-8009-exec-17" at 1:13:38

sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:467)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(TaskQueue.java:85)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskQueue.poll(TaskQueue.java:31)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1066)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: what Tomcat version ? And how do you know this thread is guilty, and not another one (just to be sure we are investigating the right problem) ?

Comment: Tomcat version:  8.0.50, when see jconsole topthread plugin, it shows this thread using more cpu.

Comment: This thread is doing nothing, there are tens of similar threads. Is is just eating more cpu than the others, or is it eating all the cpu of your computer ?